# Can SlickEdit automatically update its tag files?

Tags: ide, slickedit

I prefer [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/) for my IDE but the only way I can get it to update the tag files to incorporate code changes is to recreate the project and/or run start a re-tag manually. Is there a way to setup Slick Edit so that it automatically incorporates changes in the code base that happen after project creation.

This problem is especially noticeable when working on large shared code bases where I must check out files that have been modified by other users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I asked a question on the SlickEdit forums.

http://community.slickedit.com/index.php?topic=3854.0

EDIT: Winnar! *Options->Editing->Background Tagging of Other Files*